# When logging in remotely, can the laptop you use be traced?

Tags: security, remote-desktop, remote-access, anonymous

If you were to log in to your company's network using a remote connection but used another employee's login details, not your own, would the administrator be able to trace which laptop was used?

Comment: Your question matches much better the profile of the http://superuser.com .

Answer (score 1):

`If you were to log in to your company's network using a remote connection but used another employee's login details, not your own, would the administrator be able to trace which laptop was used?` - Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the straight answer.Even though, when I log in a window pops up saying: "the identity of the remote computer could not be authenticated due to a problem with it's security certificate. It may be unsafe to proceed. Do you want to proceed anyway"??

Comment: That is completely different thing, it is a warning about the remote server's certificate.

Comment: Sorry. I'm terribly un-techy. Just wondered how they would know which machine is used if we all connect to the same remote IP address (I'm assuming) when we're out of the office??

Comment: @Safariblonde MAC address is one possible way. There are a variety of ways they could track it.

Comment: While they can track your MAC address, and know when you log in again, they won't actually know who you are if you use somebody else's login credentials.  So they know whenever Computer A logs in, but they don't know who is behind Computer A.